# Java - FileOutputStream overwrites file, but it doesn't seem to change

Tags: java, file, overwrite, fileoutputstream

So, when I write to a file using `FileOutputStream`, it *does* change the file's contents, seen as when I read it with an `InputStream` I get exactly what I wrote. However, when I open the file in the resources directory, it remains the same as before, despite it being changed.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String edit = "Edit2";
        String fileName = "/File.txt";
        URL url = Object.class.getResource(fileName);

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(url.toURI()))) {
            fos.write(edit.getBytes());
        }

        try(InputStream is = Object.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int read = is.read();
            while (read != -1) {
                sb.append((char) read);
                read = is.read();
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

By the way, I am using IntelliJ IDEA, and have this file on the resources folder. It's just a .txt file with contents `Not changed`, so I can know if it was overwritten.

I would want to know whether this problem is related to code or not, and if it is, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I shouldn't be using `Object.class.getResource(fileName)` to open the file from the classpath, but instead directly instantiating a File object.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String edit = "Edit";
        String fileName = "resources/File.txt";
        File file = new File(fileName);

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(edit.getBytes());
        }

        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int read = is.read();
            while (read != -1) {
                sb.append((char) read);
                read = is.read();
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I believed it's related to the path, as CHN pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds silly, but try refreshing the folder before opening the file.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? Inside the IDE or in the Finder (I'm using MacOSX)?

Comment: Try on both, I haven't used IntelliJ, but as far as I know in eclipse, sometimes you will see the old file even after changing the content, so I used to refresh(F5) to get the latest. You can also try inspecting the file modified time to make sure you are writing to the same file which you are checking.

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't work. Used IntelliJ's synchronize and I noticed that after running the program the modified time didn't update.

Comment: Might be you are accessing from different path, you can check the path like this - `new File(Object.class.getResource(fileName).toURI()).getAbsolutePath()`